# MSW(Mock Service Worker) in Next js first render not working

Tags: next.js, msw

I use msw with Next js. But at First render, cannot connect api
this is index.tsx

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const Home = () => {
  const getFruit = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api");

    return data;
  };

  const { data } = useQuery(["dfa"], getFruit);
  console.log("data: ", data);

  return <div>Hello world</div>;
};

export default Home;
```

And i capture log in dev tool
[image]

In terminal **compiling /_error (client and server)..** error is showing.
I write code in mocks/index.ts like

```
async function initMocks() {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    const { server } = await import("./server");
    server.listen();
  } else {
    const { worker } = await import("./browser");
    worker.start();
  }
}

initMocks();

export {};
```

Also I check this code is running before index.tsx.
I think msw work late then first rendering. Is it right? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can follow this [official discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39695)

Answer (score 0):

Starting the worker is an asynchronous action, which may create a race condition with your application making requests on mount. If that's the case, please refer to the [Deferred mounting](https://mswjs.io/docs/recipes/deferred-mounting) recipe to enforce your application mount when the worker is ready.

> from: https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser

My Solution (Next.js 13):

```js
'use client';

import type { ComponentProps } from 'react';
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MSWContext = createContext('');

type Props = Omit<ComponentProps<typeof MSWContext.Provider>, 'value'>;

export default function MSWConfig({ children }: Props) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      // replace '@/mocks/browser' to yours
      import('@/mocks/browser')
        .then(({ worker }) => worker.start())
        .then(() => setLoaded(true));
    } else {
      setLoaded(true);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <MSWContext.Provider value={''}>
      {loaded ? children : <></>}
    </MSWContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was faced with this same problem and decided to go this route. I have to say it all looked hacky to me but it managed to fix the problem for me.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_MOCKING === "enabled") {
      import("../../mocks").then(({ initMocks }) => {
        initMocks().then(() => {
           // write your startup code here
          // boardsStore.fetchBoards();
        });
      });
    } else {
      // boardsStore.fetchBoards();
    }
  }, []);
```

I can see how this can be a problem with `SSR` and all but in my case it was sufficient, needless to say you can adapt this as a quick relief since this is not supposed to be production code anyway.