msw did not mocking useLazyQuery at first rendering
I using useLazyQuery for fetching data and mocking that request's response in development environment.
...
  const [getSiteList, { data }] = useLazyGetSiteListQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    void getSiteList({});
  }, [getSiteList]);

  console.log(data)

When I run this code it returns real api's data. But it returns mocking data when i annotate the console.log and back-annotate.
I think it would be asynchronous problem but don't know how to solve this problem.
Environment

"react": "18.2.0",
"react-redux": "8.0.7",
"msw": "2.3.0",

I want to get mocking data even if it has been first render.

solve this problem by change service mocker setup code.
async function initMocks() {
  const { worker } = await import('./browser');
  return worker.start();
}

It works well after add 'return' to worker.start().
The useLazyQuery returns mocking data even on first render.
Hint by:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73879933/mswmock-service-worker-in-next-js-first-render-not-working
https://mswjs.io/docs/integrations/browser

